# Error saying variable is not defined when it is clearly defined

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm getting an error saying my variable is not defined when it's defined just a few lines above the error.

I really don't understand why I'm getting this error and I have no idea of what could cause this error.

The error only shows up in the browser. There's no error in the terminal where my app is running.

[image]

### Content of `main.ts`

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import { History, IHistory } from '@/modules/history/History'
import App from './App.vue'
import ElementPlus  from 'element-plus'

declare module '@vue/runtime-core' {
  interface ComponentCustomProperties {
    $hist: IHistory;
  }
}

const app = createApp(App)
app.use(ElementPlus, { size: 'small' })
app.config.globalProperties.$ELEMENT = { size: 'small' }
app.config.globalProperties.$hist = History.instance()
app.mount('#app')
```

### Exported console logs

```
log.js?1afd:24 [HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...
main.ts?cd49:13 Uncaught ReferenceError: ElementPlus is not defined
    at eval (main.ts?cd49:13)
    at Module../src/main.ts (app.js:1798)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:849)
    at fn (app.js:151)
    at Object.1 (app.js:2027)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:849)
    at checkDeferredModules (app.js:46)
    at app.js:925
    at app.js:928
eval @ main.ts?cd49:13
./src/main.ts @ app.js:1798
__webpack_require__ @ app.js:849
fn @ app.js:151
1 @ app.js:2027
__webpack_require__ @ app.js:849
checkDeferredModules @ app.js:46
(anonymous) @ app.js:925
(anonymous) @ app.js:928
```

Comment: You can try to reload the IDE

Answer (score 0):

I've found the source of my issue and I think it's not really an issue since I believe it's the intended behavior.

This behavior was caused by a babel plugin ([`babel-plugin-import`](https://github.com/ant-design/babel-plugin-import)).

All I had to do to solve my problem was to import [*Element<sup>+</sup>*](https://element-plus.org/#/en-US/component/quickstart#on-demand) components instead of `ElementPlus` itself.

### Fixed `main.ts`

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import { History, IHistory } from '@/modules/history/History'
import App from './App.vue'
import { ElRow, ElCol } from 'element-plus'

declare module '@vue/runtime-core' {
  interface ComponentCustomProperties {
    $hist: IHistory;
  }
}

const app = createApp(App)
app.use(ElRow)
   .use(ElCol)

app.config.globalProperties.$ELEMENT = { size: 'small' }
app.config.globalProperties.$hist = History.instance()
app.mount('#app')
```

### Babel configuration (`babel.config.js`)

```js
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    [
      "import",
      {
        libraryName: 'element-plus',
        customStyleName: (name) => {
          name = name.slice(3)
          return `element-plus/packages/theme-chalk/src/${name}.scss`;
        },
      },
   ],
  ],
};
```